# Getting java.util.InputMismatchException?

Tags: java

So I haven't worked with Java in a while and was trying out [codingame.com](http://www.codingame.com) to see what I still remembered.
I am doing the *tutorial level*, that has this code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

/**
* The code below will read all the game information for you.
* On each game turn, information will be available on the standard input, you will be sent:
* -> the total number of visible enemies
* -> for each enemy, its name and distance from you
* The system will wait for you to write an enemy name on the standard output.
* Once you have designated a target:
* -> the cannon will shoot
* -> the enemies will move
* -> new info will be available for you to read on the standard input.
**/
class Player {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    // game loop
    while (true) {
        int count = in.nextInt(); // The number of current enemy ships within range
        String[] enemy = new String[count];
        int[] dist = new int[count];
        String closeEnemy = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            enemy[i] = in.next(); // The name of this enemy
            dist[i] = in.nextInt(); // The distance to your cannon of this enemy
        }
        for(int j = 0; j <= count - 1; j++){
            if(dist[j] > dist[j+1] ){
                closeEnemy = enemy[j];
            }
            else{
                closeEnemy = enemy[j+2];
            }
        }

        // Write an action using System.out.println()
        // To debug: System.err.println("Debug messages...");

        System.out.println(closeEnemy); // The name of the most threatening enemy (HotDroid is just one example)
    }
}
}
```

and what I need to do is assuming count is 2, I need to check which enemy is closer by comparing `dist` variables from diferent enemies.

What I did was this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

/**
* The code below will read all the game information for you.
* On each game turn, information will be available on the standard input, you will be sent:
* -> the total number of visible enemies
* -> for each enemy, its name and distance from you
* The system will wait for you to write an enemy name on the standard output.
* Once you have designated a target:
* -> the cannon will shoot
* -> the enemies will move
* -> new info will be available for you to read on the standard input.
**/
class Player {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    // game loop
    while (true) {
        int count = in.nextInt(); // The number of current enemy ships within range
        String[] enemy = new String[count];
        int[] dist = new int[count];
        String closeEnemy = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            enemy[i] = in.next(); // The name of this enemy
            dist[i] = in.nextInt(); // The distance to your cannon of this enemy
        }
        for(int j = 0; j <= count - 1; j++){
            if(dist[j] > dist[j+1] ){
                closeEnemy = enemy[j];
            }
            else{
                closeEnemy = enemy[j+2];
            }
        }

        // Write an action using System.out.println()
        // To debug: System.err.println("Debug messages...");

        System.out.println(closeEnemy); // The name of the most threatening enemy (HotDroid is just one example)
    }
}
}
```

I tried to make it work for any amount of enemies (for any count the user would insert), but when I test this it gives me the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at Player.main on line 24`

I have checked everything and I can't find the mistake and would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: There is no difference between the first block of code and the second, copy paste error?

Comment: Do you know what the problem is? This is, have you even read the Java API docs on that exception?

``public class InputMismatchException extends NoSuchElementException``

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Are you sure the distance is provided with an integer? Couldn't it be a double?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably inputting a `String` or `double` when the program is expecting an `int`. The following input works without throwing a `InputMismatchException`:

```
2
enemy1
1
enemy2
2
```

After that you get some array out of bounds exceptions which can be fixed with:

```
for(int j = 0; j < count - 1; j++){
    if(dist[j] > dist[j+1] ){
        closeEnemy = enemy[j];
    } else {
        closeEnemy = enemy[j+1];
    }
}
```